Sub-Lattices in Point Sets with Concentration on Parallel Lines
You can skip to the bottom for the question, to see if it interests you. Thank you for reading! :)
I have run across the following counting problem in the cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}_{p^3 q^3} \cong \mathbb{Z}_{p^3} \times \mathbb{Z}_{q^3}$ where $p \neq q$ is a prime integer. For the purpose of this problem, I am going to identify this larger group with the lattice $$\Lambda : = \{(i,j) : 0 \leq i \leq p^3 - 1 ; 0 \leq j \leq q^3 - 1\} \subset \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}.$$
Moreover, I will work with the following "lines" in $L$, which I define for each $0 \leq \alpha \leq p^3 - 1$ as:
$$
L_{\alpha}^p : = \{(\alpha,i) \in L : 0 \leq i \leq q^3 - 1 \}, \quad \forall 0 \leq \alpha \leq p^3 - 1,
$$
and similarly for $L_{\beta}^q$. Here is the set-up of my question. Let $X \subset L$ is a finite collection of points with $\# X \geq pq$ (here, "$\# X$" denotes the cardinality of $X$) and suppose that $X$ has the following two properties:
$(1.)$ Cardinality on the axes:  $\# (X \cap L_0^{p}) \geq q$ and $\# (X \cap L_0^q) \geq p$; and also
$(2.)$ If $\alpha,\alpha' \in \{0,...,p^3 - 1\}$ are any two integers such that $p^2 \mid (\alpha - \alpha')$, then one necessarily has that
$$
\# (L_{\alpha}^p \cap X) = \# (L_{\alpha'}^p \cap X).
$$
and similarly $L_{\beta}^q$; that is, if $q^2 \mid (\beta - \beta')$, then
$$
\# (L_{\beta}^{q} \cap X ) = \# (L_{\beta'}^q \cap X )
$$
Problem Statement: Prove or disprove the following regarding the set $X$.
There necessarily exists an element $(\tau_1, \tau_2) \in \mathbb{Z}_{p^3} \times \mathbb{Z}_{q^3}$ such that:
$$
\{(r p^2 + \tau_1, s q^2 + \tau_2 : 0 \leq r \leq p - 1, 0 \leq s \leq q - 1 \} \subset X,
$$
where the translation by $\tau$ is taken modulo addition in the appropriate group.
In other words, if $X$ satisfies $(1.)$ and $(2.)$, then it must necessarily contain a re-scaled copy of $\mathbb{Z}_{pq}$ at scale $p^2 \times q^2$.
